# VM closed ports when scanned from host

Tags: nmap, virtualbox

I have installed Metasploitable on my Virtualbox, setting up Bridged Adapter. I try to scan it with Nmap from my host machine, but I got the report:

```
Host is up (0.00029s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on 192.168.*.* are in ignored states.
Not shown: 1000 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
MAC Address: <Oracle VirtualBox virtual NIC>
```

Where is the problem now?

Comment: This is not a security question, despite the host being Kali and the VM being metasploitable. This is purely a VirtualBox networking question. What are the results if you scan from a machine that is not the host?

Comment: From Ubuntu on Virtualbox it shows that Metasploitable VM ports are opened at is should. Then I try again with main host, but turning off VPN (It was problem) and it shows normal now. Is there any chance to work from main OS (When Vpn is on) with Metasploitable?

Comment: Yes there is. Depending on your VPN client and what configuration it provides and/or how it hooks into the operating system. You already determined that the problem is with the VPN, so post that as an answer and then open a new question on how to reconfigure your VPN.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my VPN. When I turned off my VPN, Nmap scans and shows all open ports as it should on Metasploitable.